# Как в String заменить выборочные слова другим цветом

Tags: java, android

Хочу написать метод который будет проверять два String на идентичность. Первый String будет содержать правильный ответ, а второй будет частично набираться вручную. Поэтому мне нужно чтобы в результате, текст мог выделяться красным цветом, но только не весь, а та часть где есть ошибка.

```
    private void testOne() {

        int len = 0, i = 0;
        String one, two, ds = "";

        one = "hellow world";
        two = "Qellow Qorld";

        while(i < two.length()) {

            if (one.charAt(i) != two.charAt(i)) {
                ds += two.charAt(i);
                len = i;
            } else {
                ds += two.charAt(i);
            }

            i++;
        }
        Spannable ss = new SpannableString(ds);
        ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), len, i, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        numberOFresponses.setText(ss); // Вывожу результат на экран.

    }
```

Вот что у меня получилось.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
int len // дает знать с какого символа начинать закрашивать.
```

Возможно нужно это всё делать через массивы, но я не знаю как это реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(two);
        while (i<two.length()) {
            if (one.charAt(i)!=two.charAt(i)) 
               ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), i, i+1, 
               Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            i++;
        }
   numberOFresponses.setText(ss);
```

Comment: Немного не то что мне нужно, в hellow world есть две ошибки, код обнаружил только последнюю, а первую и последнюю как  закрасить ?

Comment: Так надо слово с ошибкой выделять или только символ?

Comment: Символ в слове.

Comment: Тогда всё должно быть нормально, ищите проблему у себя

Comment: Ваш вариант кода обнаружит только последнюю ошибку в слове, и выделяет символ красным. Но как мне сделать чтобы он выделил и другие ранее найденные символы в словах.

Comment: Ещё раз проверил, всё прекрасно работает. разве что i=0 в начале не добавил

Comment: Спасибо, работает